# Interchanging of order summation in proposition 1.25 [Rudin RCA]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Hello! This proposition from Rudin's RCA book.
One moment confuses me, namely how he interchanges the order of summation in that double infinite series? Can anyone give a rigorous explanation of it?

**EDIT:** I know only that theorem from Rudin's PMA. Maybe we can apply it?
[image]

I would be very grateful for comment/answer.

Comment: It's not a really a double infinite sum, but assuming your measure is positive, by Tonelli you can always interchange these sums.

Comment: @Merlinsbeard, But Rudin never mentioned about Tonelli's theorem in this book. How to prove it without Tonelli's theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tonelli's theorem is not necessary since one of the sums is finite.

Given two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ it is easy to prove using the definition of a limit that $\lim_n (x_n + y_n) = \lim_n x_n + \lim_n y_n$.  This extends to the limit of any finite sum of sequences by induction.

Hence,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{r=1}^\infty\alpha_i \mu(A_i \cap E_r) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^m\alpha_i \mu(A_i \cap E_r) \\ = \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^m\alpha_i \mu(A_i \cap E_r)  . $$

Since finite sums can be interchanged,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{r=1}^\infty\alpha_i \mu(A_i \cap E_r) \\ = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mu(A_i \cap E_r) \\ = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mu(A_i \cap E_r)$$

Comment: You wrote that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}(x_n+y_n)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}x_n+\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}y_n$? Here your $x_n$ and $y_n$ are non-negative? Are $x_n,y_n$ from extended real line? Can you clarify these moments?

Comment: This holds for any sequences of real numbers.  If $x_n \to L$ and $y_n \to M$ then $|x_n + y_n - (L+M)| \leqslant |x_n - L| + |y_n - M| \leqslant \epsilon$ if $n$ is sufficiently large. The limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. If one limit is $+\infty$ and the other is finite then this still holds. This is indeterminate if one limit is $+\infty$ and the other is $-\infty$.

Comment: But in our case both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are non-negative and can  be equal  $+\infty$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes -  $\alpha_i$ is non-negative and finite since it is the value of a non-negative (bounded) simple function on $A_i \cap E$. The measure $\mu(A_i \cap E_r)$ is of course non-negative -- and finite since $E$ is presumably a  finite set.

Comment: Note that measure $\mu(A_i\cap E_r)$ can be infinite.

Comment: Yes but that is not a problem -- everything is non-negative. With extended real numbers only $+\infty$ + $-\infty$ is not defined.

Comment: @RFZ: You're welcome.